# Checking objects for non native methods

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

im currently building an MVC Framework in NodeJS but iv'e come across a little issue, when im checking to see if a method exists in a controller im doing the following:

```
var controller = new (this.appManager.getControllerObj(this.route.controller))();
var method     = this.route.method;

if(method in controller)
{
    /*
     * Method exists within controller
     * */
}
```

But obviously the object type has native prototypes, so if I access my site with the following: `https://localhost/index/__proto__` it obviously tries to route that method.

Now I know that I can simply black list specific methods but is there a better approach to accomplish this

#### Update:

This seem's to work fine:

```
if((method in controller) && !controller.hasOwnProperty(method))
{
    /*
     * Method exists within controller
     * */
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
controller.hasOwnProperty(method)
```

Google for hasOwnProperty to learn more about it

Comment: Thanks, i have done: `(segments[1] in controller) && !controller.hasOwnProperty(segments[1])`

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? I would expect: if (controller.hasOwnProperty(method)) { // method exists }

Comment: seem's to work ok, apart from i would of expected hasOwnProperty should return true if the property is user created, it returns true with __proto__ but false for methods i have created